# Sharepoint FormField validation

Tags: sharepoint-2010, validation, formfield

I have

```
  <SharePoint:FormField 
        ID="id" 
        runat="server" 
        ControlMode="New"
        FieldName="FName" >
  </SharePoint:FormField>
```

in the webpart, and a asp.net button on it.
the field is required field. when i click the button the validation does't perform.

how can i validate the field.

Comment: no one is answering, is it possible or not to call validation from asp button click event.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, by calling FormField.Validate(); and FormField.IsValid

But you have to return the outcome of this validation manually to the user. I have not yet found a better solution.